# Comparison after colon; use "and" or "or"

Tags: comparisons, colons

does the following sentence make sense?

> In general, triple combinations are better than double: melphalan,
>   prednisone and thalidomide (MPT); bortezomib, melphalan, and
>   prednisone (VMP); or melphalan, prednisone and lenalidomide (MPR), are all
>   better than melphalan and prednisone (MT) alone.

Is that an ok thing to say that a; b; or c is better than d? Or should it be, a; b; and c are all better than d?

I am not sure how to explain, but is the sentence ok? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Stylistically, "melphalan and prednisone" may be repeated too much.